# Valgrind error: Syscall param epoll_pwait(sigmask) points to unaddressable byte(s)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, valgrind

I have the following minimal example code. What I'm trying to do is:
in a separate thread, start a `boost::asio::deadline_timer` so that every x ms a function `loop` is called, something is done, the timer re-sets itself and so this goes on until infinity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

void wait(int milliseconds) {
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(ioService, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(milliseconds));
    timer.wait();
}

class Foo {
public:
  boost::asio::io_service ioService;
  boost::thread* thread = nullptr;
  boost::posix_time::milliseconds duration;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer;
  bool shouldStop = false;

  Foo() : ioService(), duration(10), timer(ioService, duration) {
  }

  ~Foo() {
    if (thread != nullptr) {
        shouldStop = true;
        wait(15);
        ioService.stop();
        thread->join();
        delete thread;
        thread = nullptr;
      }
  }

  void start() {
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Foo::loop, this));
    thread = new boost::thread([&](){ioService.run();});
  }

  void loop() {
    if (shouldStop)
      return;
    timer.expires_at(timer.expires_at() + duration);
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&Foo::loop, this));
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.start();
  wait(1000);
  return 0;
}
```

You can compile it with

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -pthread -g -I. -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lboost_system -lpthread -lboost_thread threaded-io-service.cpp -o threaded-io-service
```

It works fine, and I'm pretty sure a while ago `valgrind` did **not** complain about it. I recently updated, and `valgrind-3.13.0` now complains:

```
==22212== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22212== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22212== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22212== Command: ./threaded-io-service
==22212== 
==22212== Thread 2:
==22212== Syscall param epoll_pwait(sigmask) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==22212==    at 0x5E62326: epoll_pwait (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==22212==    by 0x111D50: boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::run(bool, boost::asio::detail::op_queue<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation>&) (epoll_reactor.ipp:438)
==22212==    by 0x112EE8: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::do_run_one(boost::asio::detail::scoped_lock<boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex>&, boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_thread_info&, boost::system::error_code const&) (task_io_service.ipp:356)
==22212==    by 0x1129F0: boost::asio::detail::task_io_service::run(boost::system::error_code&) (task_io_service.ipp:149)
==22212==    by 0x11322B: boost::asio::io_service::run() (io_service.ipp:59)
==22212==    by 0x114C9C: Foo::start()::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const (threaded-io-service.cpp:35)
==22212==    by 0x11E8FF: boost::detail::thread_data<Foo::start()::{lambda()#1}>::run() (thread.hpp:116)
==22212==    by 0x526E44E: ??? (in /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.65.1)
==22212==    by 0x5045089: start_thread (in /usr/lib/libpthread-2.26.so)
==22212==    by 0x5E621BE: clone (in /usr/lib/libc-2.26.so)
==22212==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22212== 
==22212== 
==22212== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22212==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22212==   total heap usage: 31 allocs, 31 frees, 81,701 bytes allocated
==22212== 
==22212== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22212== 
==22212== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22212== ERROR SUMMARY: 112 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is this really an error? I found [this bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1462258) where people think it may be a bug in valgrind.

Comment: what version of gcc and boost?

Comment: ah the linked bug indicates it may depend on specific glibc versions, in which case it may be more effective to name distributions/custom repos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is indeed that bug, and it was fixed upstream (valgrind svn r16451, 2017-06-17), as found via the link you posted:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381289

> Mark Wielaard 2017-06-16 15:44:30 UTC Originally reported against
>   Fedora: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1462258
>
> According to the epoll_pwait(2) man page:
>
> ```
>    The  sigmask  argument  may  be  specified  as  NULL,  in  which  case
>    epoll_pwait() is equivalent to epoll_wait().
> ```
>
> But doing that under valgrind gives:
>
> ```
> ==13887== Syscall param epoll_pwait(sigmask) points to unaddressable byte(s)
> ==13887==    at 0x4F2B940: epoll_pwait (epoll_pwait.c:43)
> ==13887==    by 0x400ADE: main (syscalls-2007.c:89)
> ==13887==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
> ```
>
> This is because the sys_epoll_pwait wrapper has:
>
> ```
>    if (ARG4)
>       PRE_MEM_READ( "epoll_pwait(sigmask)", ARG5, sizeof(vki_sigset_t) );
> ```
>
> Which looks like a typo (ARGS4 is timeout and ARG5 is sigmask).